# Why does MyPy refuse to find anything wrong with this?

Tags: python, mypy

Is this a limitation of MyPy: that it can not infer the types that should go through `super().x`?

```
class A:
    def x(self, r: int) -> None:
        pass


class C(A):
    def x(self, *args) -> None:
        super().x(*args)


def _() -> None:
    c = C()
    c.x('')
```

No errors are found in the above code, despite `c.x('')` passing a string to `A.x` which takes an int. It seems like something that should be inferred.

---

Is there a way to get it to recognise the typing error?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't annotate `*args`, so it's implicitly `Any`. All calls involved in this code are statically valid.

If you annotate it:

```
def x(self, *args: int) -> None:
```

then mypy reports a type error. (It still won't report an error for `c.x(1, 2)`, though. That would require either uncomfortably strict rules for `*` calls, or more data flow analysis than mypy performs.)